# New Wordpress Error Message - Not seen this before

Tags: errors

I've just seen a new error message on one of my Wordpress sites that I've not come across before.

***"This request has been denied for security reasons. If you believe this was in error, please contact support."***

As usual, I hopped onto Google to see why this was coming up, but short of a few others also finding this message there's very little out there on this.

Does anyone know what it is? Is it new? A part of Wordpress?

It doesn't really offer much in the way of explanation. I'm guessing it's an IP ban of some sort, but I'm not sure where...

[image: Boring error message]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It could be that a plugin which blocks I.P addresses or Countries is causing this.

Otherwise it maybe a setting in a security plugin has caused this. Seems the message is a custom one.

Otherwise it could be something coded into a .htaccess file.

Answer (score 3):

I'm experiencing the same problem.

It turns out that my IP address has been blocked by my web host. So each time this happens, I'll have to request them to whitelist my IP (as my ISP gives out dynamic IP addresses to broadband users in residential area, so it changes every now and then)

Hope this helps..

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

This is not a WordPress message, it is either from a plugin or from your web hosting. Disable all plugins (per file access, eg. FTP), try again. If it is gone, enable all plugins separately until it happens again.
Then remove the last plugin.

Answer (score 1):

If you're using site5 hosting, they block simple passwords i.e. "123". Changing the password to something complicated fixed it.

Comment: had to talk to support still after changing

Answer (score 0):

FYI: I got this error because my password wasn't complicated enough. Host blocked it. New password solved the problem.

Answer (score 0):

PROBLEM SOLVED:
This is what site5 host had to say...

> > > The issue was with the mod_security rules, which I have whitelisted now.
> > >       The mod_security rules can be corrected only from the backend.
> > >       One of the scripts were causing the block , so I have disabled the mod_security which resolved the issue.
> > >       You will not experience the issue again.

in sum the issue is with the hosting and they are the only ones who can overwrite it.. so don't waist your time and just contact the host